# Is there an efficient way to implement an interceptor for http requests on SwiftUI?

Tags: http, swiftui, jwt, interceptor

Looking for an efficient way to implement interceptors in SwiftUI for any HTTP requests made on my app. The App uses JWT's to authenticate and fetch users specific data. As such I want to simplify token management and refresh using an interceptor. Have seen this be done in angular and was wondering if there is a SwiftUI framework or methedology to simplify the implementation.
Thanks!

I have looked into using Alamofire, however the framework looks outdated and I was unsure if it was still valid to use in a production setting.

Overall its been fairly difficult to find up to date resources in regards to this topic which has made it hard to experiment between different solutions.